# Wordpress: Links in Menu (Appearance) not entirely saved

Tags: wordpress, menu

Good day,

Just wanted to ask for possible solutions for my issue with Appearance > Menu, and to confirm if is this a server issue or not.

I transferred a WordPress site to another server, whenever I add more or less 100 links/items in the Menu and after clicking Save, only around 50-60 are left and saved, and appears on the website.

The WordPress site is just fine in its previous server (all links are saved), I assume that this is a server issue, but don't know what solutions to implement to resolve this.

By the way, the menu is displayed through Jquery Mega Menu, I tried disabling all plugins in the new server leaving the Mega Menu the only plugin enabled but still same results (only half of the links are saved).

No error messages appear after saving. php memory as I know is 256Mb, php version is 5.3.15 (according to our ISP). No fatal error messages. It just states that the menu is saved.. unfortunately cutting the number of links/pages dragged into the menu in half.

Anyone here know any solutions to this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, confirmed that this is server issue - it is related to so called "Suhosin" variable, in order to fix the problem, you need to edit (or someone with access to server configuration file) and add the following lines in **php.ini**:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000    
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

After that it is good idea to restart the Apache server (although it is not required).